# In Python, how do I add all the elements of a list to a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I'm using Python 3.7 with Django.  How do I create a set and then add all fo the elements from a list into the set?  I tried this

```
result = {}
qset = Article.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(title__icontains=x) for x in long_words)))
result.extend(list(qset))
```

but I got the error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

on the line

```
result.extend(list(qset))
```

Comment: An empty `{}` is a `dict` - to create an empty `set`, use `result = set()`

Comment: Also, a set doesn't have 'append' or 'extend' attributes. Those are for lists. Use 'add' and 'update' for sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
new_var = set(list_var)
```

If you want to do it iteratively you can use:

```py
set_var = set()
for item in iterable:
    set_var.add(item)
```

Answer (score 4):

Analogs of list's `append` and `extend` methods for sets are `add` and `update`.

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(10)
>>> s
{10}
>>> s.update([20, 30, 40])
>>> s
{40, 10, 20, 30}
```

Argument of `update` can be not only list, any iterable object: set, tuple, generator, etc. Using this method is (I guess) a little bit faster than `add`ing elements one by one in a loop.